# Converting a code to coldfusion

Tags: php, coldfusion

Looking at the following code.. i am trying to convert the following code to coldfusion

PHP Code

```
function getTransactionJs(&$trans) {
  return <<<HTML
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
  'id': '{$trans['id']}',
  'affiliation': '{$trans['affiliation']}',
  'revenue': '{$trans['revenue']}',
  'shipping': '{$trans['shipping']}',
  'tax': '{$trans['tax']}'
});
HTML;
}
```

coldFusion Code:

```
function getTransactionJs(&$trans) {
  return <cfoutput>
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
  'id': '{$trans.id}',
  'affiliation': '{$trans.affiliation}',
  'revenue': '{$trans.revenue}',
  'shipping': '{$trans.shipping}',
  'tax': '{$trans.tax}'
});
</cfoutput>;
}
```

i am not sure what went wrong, but it is not displaying anything in browser, for this i created a small test case to make sure it works

Comment: Please don't take this as being rude, but that's not even close. I recommend you read a little more about how to code ColdFusion, since this is basic stuff like outputting variables. learncfinaweek.com is a great resource.

Comment: When translating from one programming language to another, it's often a good idea to translate the code to English first, and then from English to the second programming language.

Comment: makes sense, but why english, it does not english

Comment: It comes under the general category of you should know what the code is supposed to accomplish before you try to write it.  If English is not your primary language, then use whatever is.